# Series pass configuration logic level MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to create a switch for a negative supply rails -12V/2A using a MOSFET.
I'm not sure how to implement the design in a negative rails,
We want the voltage drop in the NMOS to be less than 0.1V at 2A. So we want Rds(on) to be less than 33mOhm
any help on how to implement the design will be appreciated.
I'm looking for a circuit equivalent to this one but with the changes to operate a -12V negative supply
[image]

Comment: Please clarify that you are actually wanting to provide power switching for a negative twelve volt supply. The circuit configuration that you are showing is what is typically used for a positive voltage power supply.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a circuit configuration like this:

[image]

Make sure to tie the GND of the 3.3V GPIO signal source to the GND of the -12V supply. Also when selecting an NMOS FET that you make sure that it can handle the 12+3.3V = 15.5V on its Gate with respect to its Source. Many medium power NFETs with low RDSon should work in this application. It does not need to be a logic level FET.

Answer (score 2):

@Michael's circuit will work fine, you could also consider this one which preserves the same logic (high = on):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxe08P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gate sees +12V with respect to the source when on, so a MOSFET capable of handling +/-20V and rated for Rds(on) at 10V would be good, for example, the Toshiba [SSM6K504NU](http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=13720&prodName=SSM6K504NU), but there are many possibilities.

That particular MOSFET should have Rds(on) of < 33m\$\Omega\$ even at 100°C Tj.

Turn-on is a bit 'softer' because the gate charge is supplied through R1, while turn-off is the same (quite slow) since the gate charge is discharged through R2. Watch the SOA limitations of the MOSFET you have in mind.

Comment: this circuit is to replace a relay, it will not be used in pulsed mode.
on/off switch it doesn't have to be fast but it has to be stable.
the operating point will be -12V current 2.5A  in continuous mode,will be mounted on a FR4 pcb.
this mosfet SSM6K504NU is capable of handling this power? it will need a heatsink?

Comment: Worst case resistance is around 20m\$\Omega\$ at Tj=25°C, maybe 30m\$\Omega\$ when very hot, so using the latter value Pd = \$I^2 \cdot Rds(on) \$ = 190mW. That will cause about 10°C rise maximum when mounted according to the datasheet test conditions (read the datasheet, but about 645mm^2 ~= 1" square copper pad), at room temperature more likely around half of that **typically**.

Comment: Is there any way to improve this schematics to reduce Mosfet turn-off delay

Comment: Yes, add the standard 2 cent PNP+NPN emitter follower gate driver between the resistor and the gate, or just lower the value of the resistor (wastes power).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if i understand well, is something like this, is this correct?

Comment: I did not double checked it, but I assume that your solution is not going to work because the MOSFET will be always ON.

Comment: Hi vtolentino, Can you please elaborate on this,what do I have to change in the drawing to make it work. I appreciate it

Comment: Michael and Spehro have already provided you with modified versions of your original circuit, and they work very nicely.